# leastsq run but the parameters are unchanged python

Tags: python, least-squares

I don't managed to make leastsq run with
The programme etude is run 5 times but there is no change of the parameters p[0] and p[1].
I launch the etude file witch produce a file of data witch I read by the Read_And_Save_Value fonction. The data print depend on the p[0] p[&] paramaters.

The template is launch by Lancer_Etude it remplace the etude file by the etude.template with the caractère $A and $B are remplaced by their actual value.

```
def Read_And_Save_Value(p,x):
    fichier = open( "sechage_granger.dat", "r") # ouverture en lecture
    txt = fichier.read()
    fichier.close()
    b1 = zeros(23)
    b2 = zeros(23)
    for i in range(6, 29):  
        print 'i', i
        line = txt.split("\n")[i] # iere ligne de donnees
        line = line.split(" ") # le separateur utilise a l'ecriture

        b1[i-6] = float(line[1])
        b2[i-6] = float(line[3])

    print 'b1', b1
    print 'b2', b2 

    c= [0,24, 46, 143, 166, 190, 388, 646, 843, 1011, 2015,
2853, 3554, 4514, 5187, 6046, 6525, 7222,
7923, 8877, 10415, 11068, 12317, 13251, 14757, 15843, 
17447, 18459,   19874, 22325, 24216, 
27071, 33651, 39987, 103995, 108660,109000]

    def f_int(p,x):
        return UnivariateSpline(b1, b2, s=2)(x)

#x = s(c)
plt.plot(b1, b2, '.-')
#plt.plot(c, x)
plt.show()

return f_int(p,x)

def Lancer_Etude(p,x,C0,Ceq):
    file_in = open('etude.template', 'r')
    file_out = open('etude', 'w')

    dico = dict(A=p[0], B=p[1],C0=C0, Ceq=Ceq)

    for line_0 in file_in.readlines():
        line_1 = Template(line_0).substitute(dico)
        file_out.write(line_1)
    file_in.close()
    file_out.close()

    os.system('bash ./launch_study.sh')

    return Read_And_Save_Value(p,x)

# Define the error
def residuals(p,x, y):  
    fichier.write(str(p[0])+";"+str(p[1])+"\n") # ecriture d'une ligne de donnees (choix arbitraire du format)

    print 'x'*80
    print 'fin etude'
    #print 'fres', fres
    print 'y', y

    err = y - Lancer_Etude(p,x,150.,50.)
    fichier.write('erreur -> ') 
    fichier.write(str(sum(np.multiply(err, err)))+"\n") 
#   print 'err', err

    return err
```